# MongoDB query using aggregation not returning expected results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a few documents that look like this example:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("540f4b6496f35c16af001dc4"),
  "groups": [
    1,
    46105,
    46106,
    53241,
    55397,
    55406,
    62840
  ],
  "vehicleid": 123,
  "vehiclename": "123 - CAN BC",
  "totaldistancetraveled": 472.0,
  "date_num": 20140901
}
```

I need to find the total distance driven by all vehicles that belong to group 46105 and where theie `date_num` matches with 20140901.

I tried the following aggregation query:

```
db.vehicle_performance_monthly.aggregate(
           { $unwind : "$groups"},
           {$group:
           {_id: "$groups",           
           totalMiles: { $sum: "$totaldistancetraveled"}}},
           {$match:{_id: {$in:[46106]}},{"$date_num":{$in:20140901}}}
           )
```

But multiple matches are not being returned. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
db.vehicle_performance_monthly.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        groups : 46106,
        date_num : 20140901
    }
}, {
    $unwind : "$groups"
}, {
    $match : {
        groups : 46106
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$groups",
        totalMiles : {
            $sum : "$totaldistancetraveled"
        }
    }
} ]);
```

Analysis for your original answer:

```
db.vehicle_performance_monthly.aggregate(
       { $unwind : "$groups"},
       {$group:
       {_id: "$groups",           
       totalMiles: { $sum: "$totaldistancetraveled"}}},  // $group doesn't map "date_name" then it will lost.
       {$match:{_id: {$in:[46106]}},{"$date_num":{$in:20140901}}} // syntax error: {$match:{_id: {$in:[46106]}},{"$date_num":{$in:20140901}}}  should be   {$match:{_id: {$in:[46106]},"$date_num":{$in:[20140901]}}}
       )
```

$match first to improve performance